# FEDEX Tracking API Error Msg: 'The resource you requested is no longer available. Please modify your request and try again.'

Tags: php, rest, fedex

Here is the situation, I'm creating an API that gets the tracking status from FedEx based on the tracking number.

Here is my code:

```
   $url = 'https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/'.$fedExTrackingNumber;
   $api = new App_ApiTransaction('POST', $url, '', App_ApiTransaction::ENCODE_JSON);
   $api->addHeader( 'Authorization', 'Bearer '. $accessToken);
   $api->addHeader( 'X-locale', 'en_US');
   $api->addHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Also, here is the tracking number that I have used. 123456789012

Why would that error code show up? Could it be the tracking number? I do have the access token.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a URL for the official documentation that you're following? The endpoint you are using doesn't match what I'm finding on the web

Comment: Here is the link that I'm using: https://www.fedex.com/developer-portal/en-us/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/Track%20by%20Tracking%20Number This is a custom HTTP request that I'm using.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that helps! First, I'm seeing that specific endpoint in their documentation, although I could be missing something. Instead, I think you want the [TCN](https://www.fedex.com/developer-portal/en-us/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/TCN) or [tracking number one](https://www.fedex.com/developer-portal/en-us/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/Track%20by%20Tracking%20Number)? Second, is that `Bearer` just a sample or is that your actual code? If the latter, you need to setup [authorization](https://www.fedex.com/developer-portal/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html).

Comment: That would be the Bearer, so I would have to set up the authorization to access the data?

Comment: Update, I did add the auth token, however, I'm still getting the same error.